# How to add a second launcher icon to an app previously published in the Market with only one launcher icon?

Tags: android, icons, upgrade, launcher

I want two launcher icons for two different activities in my application. I have added this to the Manifest file.

```
<activity ... android:name=".TestActivity01"> 
  <intent-filter> 
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
  </intent-filter> 
</activity> 
<activity ... android:name=".TestActivity02"> 
  <intent-filter> 
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
  </intent-filter> 
</activity>
```

This works fine if you install the app with the two launcher icons since the beginning. 
My problem is that I have already published my app in the Market with one icon launcher only. If I just add the intent-filter with the .Main and .Launcher options to another activity it doesn't work when the users update the app. They keep having one icon only. If they uninstall the previous version and then install the new one then they will have the two icons.

Question: is there a way I can force a "clean" upgrade? I don't have problems with loosing information.

Answer (score 1):

Hi first time u have update the application in android market one lancher and second time u have update the next version your application in this application u have check the package  u can modify the mainfest file another lanching activity what is the use two lanching icons (user download u r app this  time another app download option is it correct ) In android market every updations only compare to package only.